# Set permanent docker build --build-arg value for my environment

Tags: docker, proxy

Working behind a corporate proxy - I need to build my docker images like

`docker build --build-arg http_proxy=http://my.proxy:80 .`

and that's fine.

I have a script that I've checked out that does a bunch of docker builds - and that's fail because it's not reaching the proxy.

Is there a way to set my local environment to always use my proxy settings when doing docker build?

I did look at creating an alias - but that seems a bit gnarly giving there's a space between the commands? Is there a simple global config I can modify?

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure to configure the http_proxy setting for the docker deamon as described in [HTTP/HTTPS proxy](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/#httphttps-proxy).

This configuration should be enough for docker to pick it up and use it when building the image. However, If the internal commands that the dockerfile is running are creating some custom connections, this configuration may not be picked up properly.

The proxy settings can be picked up from docker info:

```
$ docker info | grep Proxy
Http Proxy: http://localhost:3128
Https Proxy: http://localhost:3128
```

You can use the values provided picked up by docker info.

However, what I recommend is to install a tool to transparently route all the traffic to the http proxy. That way you can forget about the proxy and all tools on your machine should work seemlessly.

If you are on linux, there is [redsocks](http://darkk.net.ru/redsocks/). The is also a [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/munkyboy/redsocks/) for it if you don't want to install it directly on the machine. For other platforms you can use [proxycap](http://www.proxycap.com/).

Comment: Yip - this answer isn't helpful. My understanding is that the proxy settings you've set for docker - aren't applied for things like fetching npm or apt-get dependencies during build. See: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/24697